# What, in short words, does the GCC option -fipa-pta do?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization

According to the GCC manual, the `-fipa-pta` optimization does:

> `-fipa-pta`: Perform interprocedural pointer analysis and interprocedural modification and reference analysis. This option can cause excessive
>   memory and compile-time usage on large compilation units. It is not
>   enabled by default at any optimization level.

What I assume is that GCC tries to differentiate mutable and immutable data based on pointers and references used in a procedure. Can someone with more in-depth GCC knowledge explain what `-fipa-pta` does?

Comment: interprocedural pointer analysis and points-analysis is hard to explain in "few short words". what are you looking to do with them?

Comment: i'm just trying to understand it as i was unable to find documentation/information on it. i know that looking at the implementation would be an option but that'd take me a lot of time.
i assume it's trying to determine the possible values a pointer/reference refers to and which are modified; using a a pointer analysis algorithm such as steensgaard or andersen. am i right with that assumption? that'd already help me.

Comment: gcc developer wrote a blog post on -fipa-pta https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/06/fipa-pta.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the word "interprocedural" is the key here.

I'm not intimately familiar with gcc's optimizer, but I've worked on optimizing compilers before. The following is somewhat speculative; take it with a small grain of salt, or confirm it with someone who knows gcc's internals.

An optimizing compiler typically performs analysis and optimization only within each individual function (or subroutine, or procedure, depending on the language). For example, given code like this contrived example:

```
double *ptr = ...;

void foo(void) {
    ...
    *ptr = 123.456;
    some_other_function();
    printf("*ptr = %f\n", *ptr);
}
```

the optimizer will not be able to determine whether the value of `*ptr` has been changed by the call to `some_other_function()`.

If *interprocedural* analysis is enabled, then the optimizer can analyze the behavior of `some_other_function()`, and it may be able to prove that it can't modify `*ptr`. Given such analysis, it can determine that the expression `*ptr` must still evaluate to `123.456`, and in principle it could even replace the `printf` call with `puts("ptr = 123.456");`.

(In fact, with a small program similar to the above code snippet I got the same generated code with `-O3` and `-O3 -fipa-pta`, so I'm probably missing something.)

Since a typical program contains a large number of functions, with a *huge* number of possible call sequences, this kind of analysis can be very expensive.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'll investigate further from here. I accepted your answer for now, but perhaps someone with more in-depth gcc knowledge can still contribute.

Answer (score 0):

As quoted from [this article](https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/06/fipa-pta.html):

The "-fipa-pta" optimization takes the bodies of the called functions into account when doing the analysis, so compiling

```
void __attribute__((noinline))
bar(int *x, int *y)
{
  *x = *y;
}

int foo(void)
{
  int a, b = 5;
  bar(&a, &b);
  return b + 10;
}
```

with -fipa-pta makes the compiler see that bar does not modify b, and the compiler optimizes foo by changing b+10 to 15

```
int foo(void)
{
  int a, b = 5;
  bar(&a, &b);
  return 15;
}
```

A more relevant example is the “slow” code from the “[Integer division is slow](https://kristerw.blogspot.se/2017/05/integer-division-is-slow.html)” blog post

```
std::random_device entropySource;
std::mt19937 randGenerator(entropySource());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> theIntDist(0, 99);

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
  volatile auto r = theIntDist(randGenerator);
}
```

Compiling this with -fipa-pta makes the compiler see that theIntDist is not modified within the loop, and the inlined code can thus be constant-folded in the same way as the “fast” version – with the result that it runs four times faster.